# Rails + YAML : Parsing error when loading YAML data from application.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

To seed my database with airport names, I use *application.yml* to define a collection of airports:

```
AIRPORTS:
  - name: "Charles de Gaulle"
    city: "Paris"
    country: "France"
  - name: "Orly"
    city: "Paris"
    country: "France"
```

Using Rails Command (rails c) to test, I have:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > ENV['AIRPORTS']
 => "[{\"name\"=>\"Charles de Gaulle\", \"city\"=>\"Paris\", \"country\"=>\"France\"}, {\"name\"=>\"Orly\", \"city\"=>\"Paris\", \"country\"=>\"France\"}]"
```

which is a string! Then, when typing the following, I have an error:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > YAML.load(ENV['AIRPORTS'])
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected ',' or '}' while parsing a flow mapping at line 1 column 2
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse'
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from (irb):2
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Hassen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What I'm expecting (what I want) is to have an array of objects, so I can seed my database with the following code:

```
YAML.load(ENV['AIRPORTS']).each do |airport|
    AirPort.create airport
    puts 'airport created: ' << airport.name
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: how do you import the content of the yml file in the env variable?

Comment: seems the content is simply not 'evaled', weird since `eval ENV['AIRPORTS']` is ok

Comment: It is automatically imported, since running `rails c` imports application.yml (and other .yml files in the config folder).

Comment: as far as I know this is not a default behaviour, you must have a gem which does the trick

Comment: After googling, you're right, apneadiving. `rails c` doesn't, by default, load the ENV variables! But I really don't know why this is the case for me! Do you think this is why I've got the problem?

Comment: I guess you've some code in an initializer or a gem like figaro

Comment: Indeed, I have figaro gem. Seems that it is the reason why I have access to `ENV` variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using figaro `gem` this would do the trick:

```
(eval ENV["AIRPORTS"]).each do |params|
  Airport.create! params
  puts "Airport created: #{params["name"]}"
```

I usually use a simple initializer `load_config.rb` like:

```
YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'application.yml'))['AIRPORTS'].each |params|
  Airport.create! params
  puts "Airport created #{params['name']}"
end
```